# passing int value as a parameter in thread constructor in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new to Java programming and I want to pass an integer value as a parameter in the constructors of thread. Can anyone help me? My code shown below:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Thread;
import java.util.Scanner;

class A implements Runnable {
    int count;
    int a;
    Thread t;

    A(int i) {
        synchronized (this) {
            a = i;
            // count=Integer.parseInt(a);
            count = a;
            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        inc();
    }

    public synchronized void inc() {
        try {
            if (count != 0) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    ++count;
                    System.out.println("Incrementing pre " + count);
                    // String p = String.valueOf(c);
                    // System.out.println("Incrementing in value of p " + p);

                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    // int cminus = count-1;
                    // --count;
                    new B(count);

                    // String p = String.valueOf(cplus);
                    // System.out.println("Incrementing in p  " + cplus);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Count values cannot be negative");
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

class B implements Runnable {
    int count;
    int a;
    Thread t;

    B(int i) {
        a = i;
        // count=Integer.parseInt(a);
        count = a;

        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        dec();
    }

    public synchronized void dec() {
        try {
            if (count != 0) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    --count;
                    System.out.println("Decrementing first " + count);
                    // String p = String.valueOf(count);
                    // System.out.println("Value of p: " + count);

                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    // ++count;
                    // System.out.println("p out" + p);
                    new A(count);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Count values cannot be negative");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

class Thread_array extends Thread implements Runnable {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException {
        int z;

        System.out.print("Enter your desired number: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int dj = input.nextInt();
        int[] array = new int[dj];
        for (z = 0; z < array.length; z++) {
            array[z] = 0;
            System.out.print(" " + array[z]);
        }

        System.out.println();
        new B(dj);
        new A(dj);
    }
}
```

To summarize, I would like to be able to do this:

```
   t =  new Thread(this, i);
```

instead of

```
   t = new Thread(this);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why create the Runnable class if you're not even going to use it? The solution is to use  your Runnable's constructor and then start the Thread with the Runnable object. Please read a basic threading tutorial as you will see how to solve this immediately if you'd just put in a little effort.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but whenever I see a class implementing `Runnable`, then spawning a `Thread` and passing the current object to the thread I get severely confused about what's going on, especially when there's shared state involved. Why not separate the logic of the `Runnable` into a different class?

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    int count;
    int i;

    public ThreadTask(int i) {
        this.i = i;
        this.count = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        inc();
    }

    public synchronized void inc() {
        try {
            if (count != 0) {
                synchronized (this) {
                    ++count;
                    System.out.println("Incrementing pre " + count);
                    // String p = String.valueOf(c);
                    // System.out.println("Incrementing in value of p " + p);

                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                    // int cminus = count-1;
                    // --count;
                    new B(count);

                    // String p = String.valueOf(cplus);
                    // System.out.println("Incrementing in p  " + cplus);
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Count values cannot be negative");
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // ...
        }

  }
}
```

Then class A:

```
class A {
    Thread t;

    public A(int i) {

        ThreadTask task = new ThreadTask(i);
        t = new Thread(task);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you actually look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html), the first example answers your *EXACT* question.

It looks a lot like this:

```
class ThreadThatUsesAnInt extends Thread
{
    private int myIntVariable;

    ThreadThatUsesAnInt(int someInt)
    {
        myIntVariable = someInt;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        /* do stuff */
    }
}
```

Here's a handy hint about how to solve problems with java:

If you have a question about how to use a class, do the following google:

```
java 6 <ClassName>
```

Or... In this case:

```
java 6 Thread
```

The first result is almost always the javadoc, which is basically the whole key to using java.

Comment: Probably because you usually shouldn't subclass `Thread`, but use a `Runnable` instead.